# IOS app review meta data rejected. Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed

Tags: ios, flutter, metadata

I don't know where to answer these questions. I uploaded the answers in app review information note section but didn't work. What should I do?

The review message is attached below.

---

> **Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed**

We’re looking forward to continuing our review, but we need a bit more information about your business model and your users to help find the best distribution option for your app. Our preliminary review of your app suggests that your app may be a good fit for our Apple Business Manager program, which is designed specifically for business apps.

Next Steps

Please review the following questions and provide as much detailed information as you can for each question.

1. Please describe which kinds of users you expect will use your app. Some common kinds of users are:

- Users who are part of a single company (including its partners, employees and contractors)
- A limited number of companies which are clients of the developer
- The general public

2. Identify the specific countries or regions where you plan to distribute your app.
3. What features in the app are intended for use by general App Store users?
4. How do users obtain an account?
5. If there are any paid aspects of the app, such as for opening an account or using certain features in the app, please explain how users access the paid content.
6. Who pays for the paid content?

Since your App Store Connect status is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit App Store Connect to select your app and revise the desired metadata values. Once you’ve completed all changes, reply to this message in Resolution Center and we will continue the review.

Comment: it appears to me you need more information includes 1-6

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because app store review questions are off-topic

Answer (score 2):

Go to **App Review page** where your required changes are listed.

At **the bottom of the page you should see a "Reply to App Review"** link with a small icon.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue there is not a place or link to provide answers for those questions But Answer these questions under Notes will simply solve my issue

** you will see a section called Notes under your app submission screen (In The same screen you uploaded the screenshots for your app)

[image]

**Use this format to answer the questions under Notes otherwise it won't be afected**

> 1. Is your app restricted to users who are part of a single company? This may include users of the company's partners, employees, and
>    contractors.
>     Answer - your answer
> 2. Is your app designed for use by a limited or specific group of companies?  
>    Answer -  your answer
>
> - If yes, which companies use this app?
> - If not, can any company become a client and utilize this app?
>    Answer -  Your Answer
>
> 3. What features in the app, if any, are intended for use by the general public?
>     Answer -  your answer
> 4. How do users obtain an account?
>     Answer - your answer
> 5. Is there any paid content in the app and if so who pays for it? For example, do users pay for opening an account or using certain features
>    in the app?
>     Answer - your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate to the app in Appstore Connect, click on "Version History" and then click on "Resolution Center".  On that screen is a form where you can reply to the inquiry from Apple. It took me longer than expected to find it.

Comment: Resolution center is blank to me, not sure where should I fix it

Comment: i didn't find Version History and "Resolution Center" any queries

Comment: Yeah.  The interface may have changed sometime in the last two years.